# Have my own domain now. How to migrate from dyndns

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, nas

I usually pay dyn.com for dynamic dns in order to access my home servers (webserver on ubuntu, home assistant, synology, etc...). I now register for my own domain name, say example.com, from namecheap, and want to stop using dyndns.biz. I don't know how I could achieve the same functionality after stopping the dyndns.

My use cases before having my own domain.

1. http://xxx.dyndns.biz/weewx - to access my weather website hosted on my home server ip 192.x.x.14. The web content is in var/www/html/weewx folder
2. http://xxx.dyndns.biz:4002 - to access my Calibre ebook hosted on my Synology NAS, local ip 192.x.x.4. I use port forwarding on my pfSense to point it to the right server/port

With my own domain name https://example.com (using let's encrypt ssl):
a) I can access my weewx without problem by https://example.com/weewx. The website content is on my same home server, and in var/www/example.com/weewx folder. Apart from weewx folder, I also create other folders for other websites
b) To access my Calibre server on my Synology, I don't know how to achieve it; because when I type https://example.com:4002, it won't connect to my Synology server. I understand that because https has to stick to port 443. Before I implement let's encrypt ssl, no problem with port forwarding.

FYI, my web server, 192.x.x.14, is running Ubuntu 18.04/Apache.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You'd need to tie your new domain to your IP. If you do have a dynamic IP this is usually not supported. In that case you'd either have to setup your own DynDNS service or host your stuff on a rented server. Alternatively you might be able to get a static IP from your ISP.

Comment: Synology gives you a free `*.synology.me` domain that works with their built-in dynamic IP client

Answer (score 1):

> https has to stick to port 443

No, it really doesn't.

However, your old configuration had *plaintext* HTTP on port 4002. You generally cannot run HTTPS on the same IP:port as plaintext HTTP (even if it's a different domain name). So make sure that you really changed all relevant settings.

Alternate ports are not disallowed, they are just rare because nobody *wants* to have to remember the port and type it every time – if you host multiple sites, it's easier to have multiple domain names instead.

(To achieve this with only one IP address, you could configure your home server to host a subdomain such as `syno.example.com` and configure it as a *reverse proxy* that forwards requests to the NAS. In this case, the HTTPS certificates would be put on the home server, not on the NAS.)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting reverse proxy. I got it working. Now all main/subdomains share the same let's encrypt wildcard certificate.